# Rules realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to create a rule, which when one login account reads and writes to the database, can you help me, and is there something wrong with my code?

this my rules database

```
{
  "rules": {
    "User": {
      "$uid": {
     ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
        }
    },
      "Layanan Nasabah": {
       ".read": "root.child('User/' + auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "root.child('User/' + auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    }
}
```

this my codes

```
database.child("Layanan Nasabah").child(mAuth.getUid()).setValue(new pengaduan
            (getNo,getNo_Tiket,getNama_Penelpon,getPenelpon1,getPenelpon2,getEmail,getPertanyaan,getTertanggung,getNo_Polis,getObyek,getCatatan)).addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
        Toast.makeText(TambahActivity.this, "Data Berhasil Disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(TambahActivity.this, OnprogressActivity.class));
        finish();

    }).addOnFailureListener(e ->
        Toast.makeText(TambahActivity.this, "Data Gagal Disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
}
```

Comment: What isn't working about the security rules that you shared? Can you show the minimal code that doesn't work against these rules?

Comment: this my codes coach

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: yes sir, I have edited again, please check sir @AlexMamo

Comment: Since you're writing to `/Layanan Nasabah`, it seems that no `/User/$uid` exists. You might want to double check the UID by adding `Log.i("Firebase", Firebase.getAuth().getCurrentUser().getUid());` just before the call to `setValue()` and check if that value exists under `/User` in the database.

Answer (score 0):

**From what I understand you want only logged in users (authenticated users) to read/write to nodes in your database.**

This rule:

```
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
```

Means that any **authenticated user** can only write to **his own** uid.

In `users` node, you already did what you are asking for:

```
//because this means any authenticated user can read and write their 
//own nodes (UIDs)

"User": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

If you also want that authenticated users only can read and write to `Layanan Nasabah` node, you can do this:

```
"Layanan Nasabah": {

 "$uid":{

   ".read": "root.child('User/' + auth.uid).exists() && auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",

   ".write": "root.child('User/' + auth.uid).exists() && auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"

 }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work sir

Comment: Check the UPDATE to see if this fixes your problem.